# Let $i :X \rightarrow X^{**}$ and $j : X^* \rightarrow X^{***}$ be natural embeddings. Then $Q := j \circ i^*$ is a projection with $Q(X^{∗∗∗}) = X^∗$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, projection, dual-spaces

[image]

---

I would to like to ask two questions in line 3 of the given proof of the proposition.

My first question would be how does $Q\circ j = j$ imply image of $Q = j(X^*)$. The image of $Q$ equals to $Q(X^{***})$ but I couldn't find such a equality which links $X^*$ and $X^{***}$ together.

My second question would be how could I prove that image of $Q = X^*$ if the image of $Q = j(X^*)$.

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't remember what is the definition of "natural embedding", but would it make sense that it implies $i^*(X^{***})=X^*$ when $i$ is a natural embedding?

Comment: @Surb Yes, $i^*$ is onto since $i^*\circ j=Id_{X^*}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, $Q\circ j=j$ seems useless. Just say$$Q(X^{***})=j\circ i^*(X^{***})=j(X^*),$$the last equality being due to the fact that $i^*$ is onto since $i^*\circ j=Id_{X^*}$ (or: since $i$ is 1-to-1).

For your second question, the author just makes his original sentence more correct when he replaces his (invalid) ${\rm im}(Q)=X^*$ by his (correct) ${\rm im}(Q)=j(X^*)$. His first rough formulation was motivated by the fact that $j$ is an embedding.

And here is my answer to Surb's new question (in the comments below, about $i^*\circ j=Id_{X^*}$):

- The embedding $i:X\to X^{**}$ (where $X^*$ denotes the [topological dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Continuous_dual_space) of $X$, with the strong topology) is defined by $(i(x))(\varphi)=\varphi(x)$.
- Its [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Transpose_of_a_continuous_linear_map) $i^*:X^{***}\to X^*$ is defined by $i^*(\psi)=\psi\circ i$.
- The embedding $j:X^*\to X^{***}$ is defined the same way as $i$: $(j(\varphi))(\rho)=\rho(\varphi)$.
  Now,$$[(i^*\circ j)(\varphi)](x)=[(j(\varphi))\circ i](x)=(i(x))(\varphi)=\varphi(x)$$(for all $x\in X$ and $\varphi\in X^*$), hence $i^*\circ j=Id_{X^*}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on $i^*\circ j=id_{X^*}$ please?

Comment: thanks for the precision!

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Nice explanation.